# How to use Firebase Remote Config in Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-remote-config

I’m new in firebase, I want to use Firebase Remote Config to store configuration data related to my business logic and retrieve it from my HTTPS triggered Firebase Functions.

How can do that using TypeScript?

Comment: I think this is what you need: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest (remote config by default is meant for mobile apps because updating a mobile app release is much more effort than web apps, but if you want it in a web app, then you will have to do it the REST way through a server, or firebase cloud function if you will)

Comment: "retrieve it from my HTTPS triggered Firebase Functions" That seems to have nothing to do with Angular. While you may be *calling* the Cloud Functions from Angular, I removed the Angular tag and updated the title to allow folks to focus on the right topic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [REST API for Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest), but that one is focused on reading and changing the parameters not on consuming them.

In other words, the REST API allows you to programmatically do the same actions as you can do in the Firebase console, it is not a replacement for the mobile SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase-admin node sdk has been updated to include this functionality. Update to the latest version and follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc).

Comment: can you please add the link for it, I'm not able to find documentation on getting values with node.js